# JSXGraph: What is the preferred way to label axes?

Tags: label, axis, jsxgraph

I would like to label the axes in my diagrams with the respective physical quantities.

What have found is that I can either just place a text close to the arrow tips. But this means that I have to re-do that when the bounding box changes.

Or I can manually draw axes with labels.

But is there maybe another, simple and robust way to label the automatically drawn axes? The goal would be to

- not have to specify coordinates,
- have the labels near the arrow heads of the axes,
- have the text fixed (i.e. non-draggable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with something like this:

```
const board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', { 
  boundingbox: [-5, 20, 5, -5], axis:true,
  defaultAxes: {
    x : {
    name: 'X',
    withLabel: true,
    label: {
        position: 'rt',
      offset: [-10, -15]
    }
  },
  y : {
    withLabel:true,
    name: 'Y',
      label: {
        position: 'rt',
        offset: [-20, -10]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

See it live at https://jsfiddle.net/6jLrpboe/3/

Comment: Wow, this is great! May I follow up with another question? I like JSFiddle, and tried setting up my own Fiddle. So I imported JSXGraph.css and jsxgraphcore.js, and copied the HTML and JavaScript code from your Fiddle. However, running does not produce a JSXGraph graphic, but an error in the console: "<a class='gotoLine' href='#46:18'>46:18</a> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: JXG". Can you point me to what else needs to be done?

Comment: Nothing else has to be done. Please, make sure that you include jsxgraphcore.js with https. The error message is a clear sign that the loading of the library fails.

Comment: That did it. Thanks! It is a bit funny though. Because following the link with http only (not https) does show the code in the browser. Just a hint then in case it is not deliberate: On https://jsxgraph.org/wiki/index.php/Howto_include_JSXGraph_into_web_pages both links are given with http addresses.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hint. I updated it immediately. But the problem has nothing to do with JSXGraph. If an HTML file is opened in the browser using https, the browsers meanwhile insist that all included files must be loaded with https, too.

Comment: I'd suggest to also include `anchorX: "right",` for the `x.label` property to make long labels grow towards than center and avoid them being cut off. Since my ticks were also on the left/bottom I also moved the offsets to the other side: `x.label.offset=[0, 15]` and `y.label.offset=[10, 0]`